# Parts of UI vanishing when debugging xamarin project on own device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building an app,  and the debugging works fine when I use the emulator and it all looks the way I want it to.
Because I am using a barcode scanner, I started debugging on my own android device instead, but then most of my UI in one of some of the pages vanishes. (see pics)

I can't find any similar problems when I google (although that might be my poor google skills).
[Here is on my device when its all vanished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw9TD.jpg)

[Here is what it is suppose to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTcRs.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TergeoAppUI.Views.RegisterInventoryPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TergeoAppUI.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:ZXing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Tergeo.Models;assembly=Tergeo.Models"
             x:DataType="vm:RegisterInventoryViewModel"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <StackLayout>

        <Grid Padding="0,5,0,0" ColumnSpacing="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button
                ImageSource="barcode.png"
                Text="Scanna"
                BackgroundColor="#AAC0AA"
                BorderColor="Black"
                BorderWidth="3"
                HeightRequest="200"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="2" 
                Grid.RowSpan="1"
                Margin="70,10,10,10" 
                Command="{Binding GoToScanCommand}"
                />


            <Entry
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Margin="20,30,160,5"
            Placeholder="EAN, PLU..."
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Completed="{Binding OnEanEntryCompletionCommand}"
                Text="{Binding Ean}"
            Keyboard="Numeric"
                />
        </Grid>


        <Label Margin="30,2" FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding ArticleName}"/>

        <StackLayout HeightRequest="200">
            <Grid Padding="2" VerticalOptions="Fill" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label 
                     Grid.Row="1" 
                    Margin="30,2"
                    FontSize="Medium" 
                    Text="{Binding RetailPrice, StringFormat='Utpris: {0:N}'}"/>
                <Entry 
                    Placeholder="Antal"
                    Grid.Row="2" 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Grid.Column='0'
                    Margin="20,0,20,0"
                    FontSize="Medium" 
                    Text="{Binding Quantity, StringFormat='Antal: {0:N}'}"/>


                <Entry 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Margin="0,0,30,0"
                    Placeholder="Låda"
                    Grid.Row="2" 
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    FontSize="Medium" 
                    Text="{Binding Box, StringFormat='Låda: {0:S}'}"
                    Completed="{Binding OnRegistrationCompletedCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- List with all the inventoryregistration for this specific list -->
        
        <ListView 
            BackgroundColor="White"
              ItemsSource="{Binding InventoryList}"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              SelectionMode="None"
            >

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="1" ColumnSpacing="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!-- ArticleName --> 
                            <StackLayout 
                                Padding="10,0"
                                x:DataType="model:InventoryInfoModel" 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.Row="0">
                                <Label 
                                TextColor="Black" 
                                FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                                Text="{Binding ArticleName}"
                                FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <!-- Article Supplier -->
                            <StackLayout 
                                Padding="10,0"
                                x:DataType="model:InventoryInfoModel" 
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                
                                <Label 
                                TextColor="Black" 
                                FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                                Text="{Binding Supplier}"
                                FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <!-- Article Ean -->
                            
                            <StackLayout 
                                Padding="10,0" 
                                x:DataType="model:InventoryInfoModel" 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.Row="1">
                                <Label 
                                FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                                Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                                Text="{Binding Ean}"
                                FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout 
                                Padding="10,0" 
                                x:DataType="model:InventoryInfoModel" 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.Row="1">
                                <Label 
                                FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                                Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                                Text="{Binding Plu}"
                                FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout 
                                Padding="10,0"
                                x:DataType="model:InventoryInfoModel" 
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                <Label 
                                FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                                Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                                Text="{Binding Quantity, StringFormat='Antal: {0:N}'}"
                                FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout 
                                Padding="10,0"
                                x:DataType="model:InventoryInfoModel" 
                                Grid.Column="4"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

                                <Label 
                                FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                                Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                                Text="{Binding Box, StringFormat='Låda: {0:S}'}"
                                FontSize="Small"/>
                                </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout 
                                Padding="10,0"
                                x:DataType="model:InventoryInfoModel" 
                                Grid.Column="4"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

                                <Label 
                                FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                                Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                                Text="{Binding StorageName, StringFormat='Hyllplats: {0:S}'}"
                                FontSize="Small"/>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Probably issues with the layout, if you want help, post the layout so we can help you underp it.

Comment: You did mean the xaml right? So thankful if someone could figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix, apparently the default color on all text is white when you debug on an android device, so all I did was add PlaceholderColor or textcolor to all the labels/entries.